# How can I call the number of all edges of my weighted graph in R?

Tags: r, graph, igraph, weighted

I only found this code, but my graph is weighted:

```
ecount(g)
[1] 17468
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what is the number of edges in a weighted graph? Can you give a small example?

Comment: My graph counts 15 nodes and 121 edges. But it is weighed, so the sum of the weighted edges is 746.

Comment: So do you just want the sum of the edge weights?

Comment: Absolutely. Could you help me, Spacedman?